# Peeling cupcake liner from chocolate mold

Tags: chocolate, dessert

I am trying a new recipe that creates a chocolate mold by brushing chocolate inside a cupcake container. The challenge now is to get the paper off the chocolate mold. It seems to be sticking to the point I would have to mess up or break the newly formed chocolate mold. I have them in the freezer now to help harden the chocolate but don't know how I will get the paper off.

Comment: When you say "inside a cupcake container", do you mean a paper or foil muffin liner (like this, see image:  http://farm1.static.flickr.com/186/411034196_f7f6971cf0.jpg )?

Comment: Switch to silicone. Perfect for all peeling applications.

Answer (score 2):

I've done something like this before.

Since you are making bowls, I assume this will eventually be filled with something. Depending on what that something is, perhaps you could wait to peel the paper until after you fill it?

For instance, in my case I was making my own peanut butter cups. If I pulled the paper off with just the shell, the bowl would shatter. However, after I filled it with PB and topped it with chocolate, I put it in the freezer and it had enough structural integrity to hold up to the stress of peeling the paper off. Then, I let thaw.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate technique which may or may not be appropriate for the outcome you desire is to blow up balloons to the size of cup that is desired.  Dip the baloon in tempered chocolate, and allow to thoroughly set.  Pop the baloon, and remove the pieces, leaving behind a small chocolte bowl.

I believe I learned this technique from *Death by Chocolate* but it has been a long time.